# Spring-managed Clojure beans

Tags: spring, clojure

I'm just wondering if it's possible to create Spring managed beans backed by Clojure code (Clojure namespace I guess, would implement regular Java interface)? If so, the example would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dmitriy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried that yet, but section 3.3 of [Programming Clojure](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure) explains how to create class files with the `:gen-class` form. Use it with `:implements` and `:extends`, build a JAR from your classes and import them into your Spring project. That should - theoretically - do the trick.

I'd be very interested in any example code, too, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the way. I'd try it when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://berlinbrowndev.blogspot.com/2009/04/practical-clojure-with-swt-junit-and.html) as an example of clojure, spring, junit and swt integration.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. I'm asking how to compile, configure a Clojure class as a regular Spring-managed bean which then becomes eligible for injection into other Spring-managed beans, etc. The example shows the other way around i.e. how to use Spring ApplicationContext from Clojure code.